# GCP Cloud monitoring using terraform for allowing "Response Code Classes" in uptime alert creation

Tags: terraform-provider-gcp, google-cloud-monitoring, uptime-monitoring

So I have my terraform file where I have created my uptime check, where I am checking the SSL certs and not the uptime, configured it so just to check the cert expire.
Now suppose by default

I have Acceptable HTTP Response Code 200 allowed but if I want to allow 404 code as well so that if the website gives 404 response but still by test passes how can I allow that in the terraform code..?

so for example

```
resource "google_monitoring_uptime_check_config" "https" {
  display_name = "https-uptime-check"
  timeout = "60s"

  http_check {
    path = "/some-path"
    port = "443"
    use_ssl = true
    validate_ssl = true
  }

  monitored_resource {
    type = "uptime_url"
    labels = {
      project_id = "my-project-name"
      host = "192.168.1.1"
    }
  }

  content_matchers {
    content = "example"
    matcher = "MATCHES_JSON_PATH"
    json_path_matcher {
      json_path = "$.path"
      json_matcher = "REGEX_MATCH"
    }
  }
}
```

This is passed if I click test option
[image]

but I need to allow 404 as well so that the test will pass if the return is 404 as well.
Can anyone plz help me with the correct code to include 404 under Acceptable HTTP Response Code->Response Code Classes allow 404 and 200.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

you can specify exact response codes:

```
http_check {
    path = "/some-path"
    port = "443"
    use_ssl = true
    validate_ssl = true
    accepted_response_status_codes {
      status_class = "STATUS_CLASS_2XX"
    }
    accepted_response_status_codes {
            status_value = 404
    }
    accepted_response_status_codes {
            status_value = 302
    }
  }
```